# Implement opApply with nogc and inferred parameters

Tags: foreach, garbage-collection, d

Note: I initially posted an over-simplified version of my problem. A more
accurate description follows:

---

I have the following struct:

```
struct Thing(T) {
  T[3] values;

  int opApply(scope int delegate(size_t, ref T) dg) {
    int res = 0;
    foreach(idx, ref val; values) {
      res = dg(idx, val);
      if (res) break;
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Foreach can be used like so:

```
unittest {
  Thing!(size_t[]) thing;
  foreach(i, ref val ; thing) val ~= i;
}
```

However, it is not `@nogc` friendly:

```
@nogc unittest {
  Thing!size_t thing;
  foreach(i, ref val ; thing) val = i;
}
```

If I change the signature to

```
  int opApply(scope int delegate(size_t, ref T) @nogc dg) { ... }
```

It works for the `@nogc` case, but fails to compile for non-`@nogc` cases.

The solutions I have tried are:

1. Cast the delegate

   ```
   int opApply(scope int delegate(size_t, ref T) dg) {
       auto callme = cast(int delegate(size_t, ref T) @nogc) dg;
       // use callme instead of dg to support nogc
   ```

This seems wrong as I am willfully casting a `@nogc` attribute even onto
functions that do may not support it.

2. Use `opSlice` instead of `opApply`:

I'm not sure how to return an `(index, ref value)` tuple from my range. Even if
I could, I think it would have to contain a pointer to my static array, which
could have a shorter lifetime than the returned range.

3. Use a templated `opApply`:

All attempts to work with this have failed to automatically determine the
foreach argument types. For example, I needed to specify:

```
foreach(size_t idx, ref int value ; thing)
```

Which I see as a significant hindrance to the API.

Sorry for underspecifying my problem before. For total transparency,
[Enumap](https://github.com/rcorre/enumap) is the "real-world" example. It
currently uses `opSlice`, which does not support `ref` access to values. My
attempts to support 'foreach with ref' while maintaining @nogc support is what
prompted this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overloading the `opApply`operator you can implement an input range for your type. Input ranges work automatically as the agregate argument in `foreach` statements:

```
struct Thing(K,V) {
    import std.typecons;
    @nogc bool empty(){return true;}
    @nogc auto front(){return tuple(K.init, V.init);}
    @nogc void popFront(){}
}

unittest {
  Thing!(int, int) w;
  foreach(val ; w) { 
    int[] i = [1,2,3];  // spurious allocation
  }
}

@nogc unittest {
  Thing!(int, int) w;
  foreach(idx, val ; w) { assert(idx == val); }
}
```

This solves the problem caused by the allocation of the delegate used in foreach.

Note that the example is shitty (the range doesn't work at all, and usually ranges are provided via opSlice, etc) but you should get the idea.

Comment: I made my example too simple -- I want to support `foreach with ref`, and can't figure out how to do that with `opSlice`. I've edited above to be more clear. This _was_ the answer to the question I asked, but not the question I _meant_ to ask. Sorry!

Comment: IIRC there is also an InputRange interface that allows modification of the front element.

Comment: check if [hasAssignableElements](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range_primitives.html#.hasAssignableElements) or [hasLvalueElements](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range_primitives.html#.hasLvalueElements) are handled when you make a `foreach(ref elem, range)`

Comment: The tuple elements are assignable ... but the tuple itself is a copy of the underlying data, so assigning to the tuples by ref doesn't actually assign back to the underlying store.